# Minecraft 1.8 does not open custom made worlds correctly or not at all

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have made a few custom worlds in Minecraft 1.5 and 1.8 but they don't open or don't show any blocks/collisions (Basically, I end up falling down an endless void). I tried everything like adding ram and re-downloading Minecraft.

What am I doing wrong and how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason your 1.5 world becomes void is because 1.8 does not have a converter into the new name-based format. It only can read them, not convert.
**Note: If you have already opened your worlds in 1.8, you CANNOT retrieve it unless you have a backup.**

---

Firstly, see if you can open them in 1.5 (the version you last used).
If that works, try opening it in 1.7. Save and quit after it loads.
Now, your world is ready to be open in 1.8, as 1.7 has automatically prepared your world for the new name-based format (when you loaded it).

---

One more thing: It may be wise to turn on cheats on your world by changing `allowCommands:0` to `allowCommands:1` in your level.dat file (so that you can fly and not continuously fall into the void as your spawn point will most likely be void as it was in a generated chunk that 1.8 converted into air due to unknown values; numbers instead of names)

Comment: how about the worlds made in 1.8

Comment: opend the world in 1.5 but this happend: http://pastebin.com/tSQJPfEW

Comment: got it already, loged in with my 1.8 profile :)

Comment: okey, here is the deal: 1.5 to 1.7 works fine but 1.7 to 1.8 failes

Comment: Your world is already corrupted in the first place. Because that crash says: "Your world has invalid NBT data.", to the point where nothing is readable.

Comment: how do i fix this

Comment: You can't fix it.

Comment: so there is absolutly nothing to do to get my old world back